# Django Cms : Am I doing it wrong with placeholders?

Tags: django, django-cms, placeholder-control

Let me explain a little bit what I'm working on :

I am an intern and I have to create a friendly website back-office for people who are not really used to computer.

Thus, the back office management has to be as simple as possible ! I already put a lot of drag & drop in my plugins, the front-end is cool etc.

But a problem subsist :

the templates and placeholders.

I managed to create a demonstration template page with multiple placeholder, some in full width and some in 6 columns, 4 columns etc.

So I have something like that :

```
<div fullwidth>
  {% placeholder "title1" %} 
</div>
<div 6 columns>
  {% placeholder "text1" %}
</div>
<div 6 columns>
  {% placeholder "Picture1" %}
</div>
<div fullwidth>
  {% placeholder "text2" %}
</div>
```

Each place holder has default plugin, in order to helps users.
Ok it works great.

But what happen now if we want, in the website back-office, move the placeholder "text2" before the 2 six columns ?

It seems to be impossible to manage it dynamically.

*If you have used wordpress, you must have experienced how easy is it to manipulate content, if you want to move a Title to an other location juste drag and drop it etc.*

Then I was thinking about the multiple column, by default you would have a multiple column with one 100% width column. Up to you to reduce it.
But the problem is that it is complicate to integrate and modify.
And it is absolutely not friendly-user !

Well, in case I am not very clear, I need to manage placehoder positions dynamically or have something to manage multi columns in an easy way for the user !

I am totally lost and without idea about it.

Have you already experienced it ? What kind of option did you choose ?

It would be really great if you could share some point of view with me :)

By the way,

thank you in advance for reading my post.

EDIT : 
Have you seen this : http://www.mir.de/django-cms-demo ? This is perfectly what I want to have. But I don't know how they are doing it... And it is in German language...

Comment: `http://www.mir.de/django-cms-demo`  is not using `django-cms`

Comment: Yeah, I realised it... Then, is it impossible to have this kind or render (specially for drag and drop) in django cms ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [djangocms-cascade](https://github.com/jrief/djangocms-cascade)? I allows one to create placeholders on the fly and it should allow to order thus created placeholders.

According to its github page:

> DjangoCMS-Cascade allows web editors to layout their pages, without having to edit Django templates. In most cases, one template with one single placeholder is enough. The editor then can subdivide that placeholder into rows and columns, and add additional elements such as buttons, rulers, or even the Bootstrap Carousel.

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much, but when I'm trying to install it (for 1h now) I have this fuc**** message when I try to makemigrations :
"raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(p, module, err.message))
AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute 'message' "

Comment: You might need to configure it as per its official [documentation](http://djangocms-cascade.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html). Also there is a guide for migrating it with Django 1.6 and Django 1.7.

Comment: Yeah I followed it but still have installation problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend:

```
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-column
```

or

```
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-grid
```

Its a lot simpler compared to `djangocms-cascade`.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I installed djangocms-grid but when I create a multi-columns(grid) and create grid column inside, I can't add any plugin (like text or image) to it !!